# Getting ProtocolException runtime error Blazor project

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, protocolexception

I'm developing a simple Blazor ASP.NET CORE Web Assembly project with Visual Studio Professional 2019 version 16.8.1 (the exception also happens in version 16.8.0).

Sometimes when I start the application I get a runtime error 'Failed to launch debug adapter Exception of type `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.ProtocolException` and the project won't start in the browser.

The browser the application is starting with is the new Microsoft Edge.

The message can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: Update:  I'm using VS Community 2019 16.7 - After reading https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22012, was able to switch browser to FireFox Dev.  That works, but Chrome is still an issue

Comment: I solved this issue by always closing all the tabs from Microsoft Edge (the browser I use to debug the web app) before starting the application. I realized that it only happens if the browser is open.

Comment: reinstalling chrome solved for me, there was some sort of error in update,

Answer (score 10):

Two possible workarounds that both independently worked for me:

> I was seeing this error when Edge was set to my default browser on windows 10. Setting it back to Chrome and restarting VS allowed debugging to work again.

> Uncheck the "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)" in "Tools > Options > Debugging > General" works for me.

source: [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1262285/exception-of-type-microsoftvisualstudiosharedvscod.html)

Comment: give me an error :' visual studio the debug adapter exited unexpectedly'

Comment: Uncheck the "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)" in "Tools > Options > Debugging > General" works for me. 

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 5):

For me deleting .vs folder and rebuild did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

As [Richard Wrench](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4487788/richard-wrench) mentioned - I switched over to debug using Firefox as well.  I was using Chrome.  The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.ProtocolException' seems to have disappeared for me.  Try it.

Answer (score 1):

The uncheck JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET did not work for me but switching to Canary works

Answer (score 1):

Check if in the **Configure** method of the **Startup.cs** class in the Server Side there is the line **app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging().** This worked for me.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerManager logger)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the `Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)` in 
`Tools` > `Options` > `Debugging` > `General` works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, this is such a big issue, @Matthias my defualt browser was actually set to Google Chrome, and I then set it to Edge. In addition I then set the debug browser to use FireFox @Richard Wrench. On top of all that, I also deleted the obj and bin folders of my project before restarting VS 2019 and rebuilding my project again. This added information is because the problem doesn't have a real fixed solution, so these extra steps may help as they did for me